# Add JS Function into jQuery Validation

Tags: jquery

I want to add this function into my JS code :

JS Username validator : prevent some characters.

```
jQuery.validator.addMethod("userNameRule", function(string, element) {return !string.match(/[-\.;,`~!@#\$%\^&\*\(\)\]\+=|\/\\{\[\}'":\?><]/g);});
```

and how to add to this JS function :

```
$('#button_sign_up').click(function()
{
if(userNameRule)
{
username can't contains characters.
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used this approach:

```
$.validator.addMethod("phoneNos", function(value, element) {
        return /^\d+$/.test(value.replace(/[()\s+-]/g, ''));
    },
    "Please enter numbers or spaces only"
);

$("#myForm").validate({
    rules: {
        telephone: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 9,
            maxlength: 14,
            phoneNos: true
        },
        mobile: {
            required: true,
            minlength: 10,
            maxlength: 11,
            phoneNos: true
        }
    },
    // error Placement
});
```

The key here is that within the jQuery form validation, you specify the function name as `true` within the form elements that you want to be validated.